# How is this lantern glow effect achieved?

Tags: rendering, directx, lighting

[image]

I was wondering if anyone knows how this lighting effect is achieved. It's clearly not a bloom shader. My best guess right now is that it's a billboarded transparent sprite, which is animated to give it a pulsing effect. I'm pretty sure the visual effect is separate from the surrounding point light. If anyone could positively identify the technique that's being used, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: @Fattie I have my own game engine. https://imgur.com/a/3M8yBFp The two brush volumes to the right are animated, and yes that's minecraft textures for debugging. I already have billboarding systems and stuff, so I already know how to do everything required for this lighting. I don't believe in paying royalities. Also what you linked appears to be for a bloom shader, which has nothing to do with this. I have a bloom shader in my engine already, and it's nothing like this.

Comment: That looks like Duskwood in WoW. Is that Duskwood?

Comment: @Arthur Yes. It is.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My best guess right now is that it's a billboarded transparent sprite, which is animated to give it a pulsing effect.

Exactly that. This is simple enough even for older hardware. There's also some kind of point light involved, but the light could also be baked into a light map. So with this combination you won't even need any extra shaders.

Comment: Doesn't appear to be any change in the lighting on the post, so I think it's probably baked in.